# How to keep data type as an integer after output from python and into Excel?

Tags: python, excel, integer

I don't have any code but just thinking ahead as I'm learning python and am very new to programming. At this point, I'm learning about variables and integers are of particular interest.  I use Excel for data handling and reporting. I understand that Power query can change the data type but I'd like to know if there's a purely python way that will keep the data output as an integer for Excel.  For example, we use something similar to UPC numbers to identify our products.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'xlsxwriter' module for writing to excel and change formatting.

https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/#